# Git: Merge again from previous branch

Tags: git, git-merge

Is it possible to Merge from a previous branch and resolve conflicts with the current branch?

I have a scenario where a colleague could not access our remote repository, and so had to make changes to files in a copy of the project. I now wish to merge these files in a new branch back into the project; however, there has been other work on these files as well.

I considered branching off from an up-to-date master, clobbering the old files in the new branch with the colleague's work, and then remerging from the head of the previous branch. Ideally, I'd then be able to go through manually confirming conflicts. This would have a structure somewhat like:

```
           o-------o-------o-------o
          /               /         \
         /               /           \
--------o---------------+-------------o----->
```

where there have been no changes to the original branch at the + where I want to merge from here to the new branch.

When I attempt a Merge From from the original branch, I get "All files are up to date".

EDIT:
The actual structure of the edits is a little different from the image above, it's closer to:

```
------A-----B--------+---->   dev branch
      |      \        \
      |       B'---C`--D-->   new branch with changes
      |
      A`----C                 changes made outside Git
```

where A` is a copy of the project at A, B are changes I've made within Git, C are changes my colleague made outside Git, and C` is the state of the branch once I've copied his changes in. D is the resulting merge back from the original branch in which I wish to pick conflicts.

However, instead of D, I'm just getting C, no change. I believe this might be because the state of the branch at copying is B, and hence Git just sees the new files as a simple set of adds and deletes, nothing difficult to resolve automatically.

Comment: I added an answer, can you check if this helps and so not respond back to me?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Git via Visual Studio, which doesn't come with Git command prompt tools by default. Fortunately, they can be installed along side, and so I should be able to give it a try.

Comment: I know what you mean. I'm using Jetbrains tools and in there, Git is also provided. But I still recommend learning basic Git commands because sometimes (like now) you want more control over your doings.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the procedure to follow:**

1. Pull your main branch(master).
2. create a new branch from your main branch.
3. Copy your friends changes or the code to the new branch.
4. Add and Commit those changes.
5. Now rebase your branch with master branch so now you will get all
   changes from master to your branch.
6. Now you should resolve conflicts if you get any.
7. After resolving Conflicts, add the files and continue rebase.
8. Now, you will get your friend's changes and latest mainbranch code
   to your code.
9. Then you can push your code to new branch.

**Here is the code for all steps:**

1. `git pull origin master`
2. `git checkout -b friend_changes`
3. **Copy the changes from other folder to this**
4. `git add -A; git commit -m "Firend changes"`
5. `git rebase -i master`
6. **Resolve conflicts if any**
7. `git add . ; git rebase --continue`
8. **Now you got all changes Here**
9. `git push origin friend_changes`

[**Documentation for git rebase**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

[**Another reference**](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase)

Comment: Nice, I was totally off concerning the main question

Comment: @Nebulosar, its ok it happens. :-)

Comment: I'm missing something. I get to step 6, and then nothing: "Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/friend_changes."
Following step 7: `git rebase --continue` I get "No rebase in progress?"

Comment: Did you pull the master branch first?

Comment: As in step 1? Other than the branch I am working out of is 'Development', I've performed all the previous steps in order. 
The closest I've been able to get is to attempt forcing a manual merge via `git difftool -t vimdiff Development HEAD`; however, even this has not been too successful. This may be because the last time I used Vim was 8 years ago...

Comment: `Successfully rebased and updated`  means there are no conflicts and the rebase is successful. No `git rebase --continue` has nothing to do

Comment: If you get any `conflict` then only you should use `git rebase --continue`

Comment: I figured that that's what that meant. However, that's the issue: the two files *are* different; comparing to previous checkin shows that. I need to manually identify which of these differences are what needs to be merged: it appears to consider the changes straightforward deletes and adds from the previous version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170654/discussion-between-sravan-and-bm).

Comment: @BM-, you can vote my answer, if it was helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my underlying problem, not necessarily the actual mechanism I was looking for, but it is a resolution.

The issue was that at the time I created the branch for the external changes, I had already created some code. Git saw the order of changes for the new code as `A---B---C` where it was actually `A----C`. But the order of the changes at the time of the merge would look like `A---B---C---B` (instead of `A---C---B` which should trigger the conflict resolution) and so Git was quite happy to resolve B-C-B as just B-C.

But I didn't actually have to branch from the head of the original development branch. If instead I created the new branch from the last commit to the development branch before I made the copy to send to him, and copied his changes into this branch, merging from the development branch afterwards will carry the changes correctly.

```
-----A---B-----+--->
     :\         \
     : A`---C`---D-->
     :
     A`---C
```

In fact, I didn't even need to resolve the conflicts, Git figured that one out automatically.